# Create DELETE query by SELECTING from table

Tags: sql-server

in my project (automation-testing) I am adding a lot of data into my Database, which supposed to be deleted after running all scenarios, but in rare occasions when execution crashes I am sometimes left with records that were not deleted.

For this reason, I decided in addition store all records that were created into additional table, where I store:

1. new of the table where new record was inserted
2. name of the field used for where clause in delete statement
3. id of the record in its table

[image]

Now I am trying to select all records from table above, and use it to create delete queries.

Is it possible to do it in single query?

```
SELECT * FROM AutomationTestingData AS atd 

DELETE FROM atd.TableName WHERE atd.DeleteByField = atd.RecordId
```

Any help would be appreciated, regards.

Comment: You could use dynamic sql for this

Comment: Hi i think you have to use EXECUTE and dynamic query, build Cursor with SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' +  atd.TableName + ' WHERE ' + atd.DeleteByField + ' = ' + atd.RecordId + ';'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if i understand all what you're trying i think this can respond :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

DECLARE  @query varchar(4000);  

PRINT '-------- Deleting rows --------';  

DECLARE deleting_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' + atd.TableName + ' WHERE ' + atd.DeleteByField + ' = ' + atd.RecordId + ';'
FROM AutomationTestingData AS atd 

OPEN deleting_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM deleting_cursor   
INTO @query  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    EXEC(@Query)

    FETCH NEXT FROM deleting_cursor   
    INTO @query  
END   
CLOSE deleting_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE deleting_cursor;
```

CURSOR SQL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

EXECUTE dynamic SQL Server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you for answer, can you please tell me where do you declare 'atd' ?

Comment: @Matthewek yes sorry i'have missing, i have update answer.

Comment: This is a viable way of doing it fully automatic. One improvement: you dont have to write a delete statement for every row in adt, see the edit in my answer

Comment: I am getting 'Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ';' to data type int.' I will try to figure it out, thanks again for great solution.

Comment: you need to convert ` + adt.RecordId + ` like this ` + convert(varchar(10), adt.RecordId) + ` to fix that

Comment: Consider changing the cursor definition as in the edit of my answer, it should be faster and no need for conversions

Answer (score 2):

You could write a delete statement for each table, like this

```
delete from Company 
where  id in ( select RecordId from adt where adt.TableName = 'Company')

delete from PickListValues 
where  id in ( select RecordId from adt where adt.TableName = 'PickListValues')
```

Granted, its not really dynamic, but its still faster then dynamic sql and a cursor

**Edit**
IF you need it fully automatic, use `dynamic sql` like suggested by @pascalsanchez

I would alter the cursor however like this

```
declare deleting_cursor cursor for
select 'delete from ' + adt.TableName + 
       'where ' + adt.DeleteByField + ' in (select RecordID from adt where adt.TableName = ''' + adt.TableName + ''')
from   AutomationTestingData AS atd 
group by adt.TableName, adt.DeleteByField
```

Comment: Its a viable solution, but since it is used for 'automation-testing' I would love to automate it as much as possible :) so I don't have to remember to update this query with new tables every time, another way I figured out, would be selecting everything from my table, using java creating new class that holds all three fields, sort them, and create multiple DELETE FROM dbo." + tableName + " WHERE (" + whereColumn + " IN (" + ids + ")) thank you though

Comment: No problem, in that case you could also consider doing it in sql server, using a cursor and dynamic sql as suggested by @pascalsanchez

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntax :

```
delete T1
from Table1 T1 join Table2.T2 on T1.SomeField=T2.SomeField
where Some Condition
```